# NetBeans 20 not opening on m2 mac

Tags: java, error-handling, netbeans

I am facing problems with Netbeans 20 on my m2 macbook air
i downloaded it from the .pkg file and everything went smoothly but i try to open the app and it wont do anything not even an error like the app is not even installed. but all the files and app icon are present.

i tried restarting my mac, updating the os, deleting the app and re downloading it with brew...
i did everything but nothing seems to work

eclipse is working fine and running all the code well
i was checking for JDK java files on the mac but there is none.

what can i do please:(

Comment: that sounds like a bug, you can try openning a [ticket](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues)

Comment: Please share the mac book chip type whether it is intel or apple chip? 
Also java version and do you have multiple version of java installed.